# Write a List to internal storage onPause(), then read the List onResume()

Tags: android, list, storage, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I'm so confused. After reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file), I'm trying to write a List to internal storage `onPause()`, then read the List `onResume()`. Just for testing purposes, I'm trying to write a simple string as the example showed. I've got this to write with:

```
    String FILENAME = "hello_file";
    String string = "hello world!";

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context. MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        fos.write(string.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And I'm trying to read it in `onResume()` by calling:

```
    try {
            resultText01.setText(readFile("hello_file"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            resultText01.setText("exception, what went wrong? why doesn't this text say hello world!?");
        }
```

Which of course uses this:

```
private static String readFile(String path) throws IOException {
      FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
      try {
        FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel();
        MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
        /* Instead of using default, pass in a decoder. */
        return Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString();
      }
      finally {
        stream.close();
      }
    }
```

For some reason, `resultText01.setText(...)` isn't being set to `"hello world!"`, and is instead calling the catch exception. I'm sorry if my lingo isn't correct, I'm new to this. Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the following in your `readFile(...)` method...

```
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
```

Try...

```
FileInputStream stream = openFileInput(path);
```

Comment: You're awesome! I also had to remove the `static` from the `readFile()` method. Works well now though. (Plus I don't really know what the difference between static and non-static stuff is, so I just put them in and remove them randomly whenever I see eclipse yell at me.)

Comment: @Age: Glad to help. I hadn't spotted the `static` declaration but it might have been relevant anyway depending on the rest of your code. As a rule of thumb, don't use it unless you're sure it's needed. Try Google for 'Java static keyword' - it might bring up some stuff which will help understanding it.